# Identify if this is a load bearing wall from the blue print

Tags: walls, framing, structural

We are exploring the remodeling of our kitchen, and wondering if this wall between living room and kitchen is load bearing ?

I have attached the blue print and photo. Are there any indications in the blue print which provides this proof ?

[image: blue print]

[image: photo]

[image: 1st floor framing]

[image: 2nd floor framing]

Comment: It's easest to tell a if a wall is load bearing by looking at what is above it. please show the second floor framing plan.

Comment: I have added 2nd floor framing plan.  When you compare the two floors, the top most, right corner of the 1st floor and 2nd floor are aligned. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to figure our the drawing of the first floor are first floor and ceiling, not first floor and floor joists. (Is the first floor is a concrete slab?)

There's a 6x12 beam (triple 2x12) in the first floor ceiling supported at one end by the alcove wall.

Superimposing the top floor over the lower floor shows that above the wall with the alcove is a wall of the upstairs closet and above that a beam that's supporting the air conditioner.

So yeah, it's extremely structural.

[image]

It may be possible to fit a new beam (green) to carry the end of the 6x12 and connect them with a suitable hanger
bracket, but you'll probably need an engineer to figure out what type of beam, and there will be a big hole in the ceiling to repair. The walls at either end of the beam will probably need to be strengthened too. Additionally the 6x12 is now spanning a greater distance and may also need to be upgraded.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance! You are right. The first floor is on concrete slab. Taking it down sounds pretty complicated. I think we will need to keep the that structural support, but possibly make it a smaller column instead of the wall.